# How to show a popup/modal in a .NET MAUI Blazor app targeting macOS?

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell

I'm unable to get modals to work when targeting Mac Catalyst, and have tried 3 different approaches. The first approach was this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yM7opXlu-MU

That approach works great when targeting iOS, but when targeting Mac Catalyst I get this error: "The Parent must be of type Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PageHandler."

The 2nd approach was with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGWhgASmSto

That approach just reset the ContentPage to the 2nd ContentPage, instead of actually presenting it as a modal. The 3rd approach was using await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MyModalPage()); which also just reset the ContentPage to the 2nd ContentPage, instead of actually presenting it as a modal.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I create a demo using default maui blazor project this time.

After I create a default maui blazor with default template, I switch to Counter page. I want to display the popup when i click the button (like the image below)

Here is a small demo for **Counter.razor**,

```
@using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;

@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Open Popup</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        var popup = new PopupPage();
        App.Current.MainPage.ShowPopup(popup);

    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot,

[image]

---

It's a known issue on GitHub : [MAUI Community Toolkit Popup Displayed Out Window Bounds On MacCatalyst](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/898) , and it has been fixed in the latest Maui Community Toolkit and in .NET8.

I have tested it and here is the screenshot,

[image]

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I upgraded to targeting .Net 8 but the I'm still getting this error when I call this.ShowPopup() and supply an MCT page: "The Parent must be of type Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PageHandler."

Comment: First, you may try creating a new .net8 project with MAUI default template and just show a popup on MainPage . Does the error still occur?

Comment: Do you show the popup in a FlyoutPage or TabbedPage?

Comment: I tried that but still no luck. The project template is a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid App, and the main page is a ContentPage. The popup page is a mct:Popup page using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.

Comment: @hunterwendroff Hello, I also create a default maui blazor project. I think it works as expected. Please take a look at my updates.